# Ajax post not returning data

Tags: ajax, post, form-submit

When submitting the form with ajax no data returns. If I submit it without ajax data returns either with post or get method.

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $('#info').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "tab-rates.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "data",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#tabs-5").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
            });
        }); // Click effect     
    }); //Begin of Jquery Statement 

    </script>

<div id=\"tabs-5\"> 
                <form id=\"info\" action=\"\" method=\"POST\">
                    <select name=\"adults\" id=\"adults\">
                        <option value=\"1\">1</option>
                        <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                        <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                        <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                        <option value=\"8\">8</option>
                        <option value=\"9\">9</option>
                        <option value=\"10\">10</option>
                        <option value=\"11\">11</option>
                        <option value=\"12\">12</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"abc\">
                    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"code\" value=\"2141\">
                    <button id=\"submit\">Submit</button>
                </form></div>
```

What shall I change? Do I miss anything?

Comment: `data: "data"` means absolutely nothing. That's why it wont be working

Comment: @James you r right, Actually Antonios is sending the data as simple string so it can by any object that contains the data i.e data: {'data':'xyz','data2':'xyz2'} etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script as following:

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function () {
        $('#info').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "tab-rates.php",
                dataType: "POST",
                data: $( this ).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tabs-5").html(data);
                },
                error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
        }); 
}); //Begin of Jquery Statement 

</script>
```